# How React rerenders tree, if both parent and child components are dependent from one Redux store prop?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have `Layout` component, which checks if a user is logged in. It simply examines `user` prop in Redux store. If it is, it renders children, otherwise `Login`.

- `Layout.jsx`

```js
const Layout = ({ user, children }) => {
  if (user) return children;
  return <Login />;
};

export default connect(state => ({ user: state.user }))(Layout);
```

- `Profile.jsx`

```js
const Profile = ({ user }) => <div>{user.name}</div>;

export default connect(state => ({ user: state.user }))(Profile);
```

- App itself

```js
<Layout>
  <Profile />
</Layout>
```

The issue is when `Profile` component is rendered and I log out, I get `can not read property name of undefined`.

I expect `Profile` component not to be rendered at all, because it is how `Layout` works. But looks like React first tries updating `Profile` component and fails.

For now I ended up returning `null` from `Profile` if there is no user, but it's not ideal.

So if both parent and child components are dependent on one Redux store prop, React rerenders them from down to the top, from top to down, or simultaneously? Is there a canonical or best practice way to avoid it?

Comment: What is the user prop in `Layout`? Are you sure you aren't accidentally passing a truthy value? That is to say - what do you do to `user` when you log out?

Comment: @ajmajmajma `user` is either object or null. So when I log out it becomes `null` in the store. Hm... I doubt, but maybe you're right, I'll check it.

Comment: Hi Ramil, I'm struggling with the same thing right now. This is what i found so far: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/509. Have you found a solution? Best regards

Comment: @Mythli I haven't( Haven't been doing a lot of React since then.