# connect() Deep connected components dependent on top connected components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The following thing seems to be the cause of console error messages and also hanging my application from time to time making it as of now unshippable.

**How to reproduce tehaviour**

Lets say we have a container component CatContainer, it renders its children if the property cats is present in the state. "cats" in the state is an object like  `cats = { snowy: { height: 5, width: 10, weight: 50 }, muschi: { height: 1, width: 12, weight: 20 } }`.

For each cat in the cats object, the CatContainer renders a Cat component, passing down the name of the Cat.

The Cat component connects to the state and pulls the specific cat out of the cats state object.

If I now remove a cat from the cats state the Cat-Component still receives the cat-name from the top but the cat is no longer present in the state, yielding an exception.

What I would expect to happen is that the CatContainer deterministically renders before the Cat component in a top-down fashion.

However, this appears to not happen, yielding in somehwat undefined behaviour.

**Possible solutions I have tried**

- Safety check in Cat component aka "`muschi in cats`". This works but it would mean I need to rewrite huge parts of the application which I would want to avoid at all costs.
- Look for a way to make connect() propagate state according to the nesting level

I have googled the issue and found the following:

1. https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/509 - Indicates that > v5 which I'm using it is somehow possible to make react-redux propagate state changes top-down which would solve the cat problem.
2. [How React rerenders tree, if both parent and child components are dependent from one Redux store prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631930/how-react-rerenders-tree-if-both-parent-and-child-components-are-dependent-from) - Basically asks the same as I'm asking here.

Both links do not propose a direct solution and I believe, this question is very relevant to everyone using react-redux in a more advanced way.

To anyone stumbling upon this, I have the following duct-tape solution in mind which I would really like to not implement.

1. Wrap connect and make it accept a "nestingLevel" and "renderedNestingLevel" context prop
2. Increment "nestingLevel" and pass down "renderedNestingLevel" after component wrapper component has updated
3. Block renders in the `shouldComponentUpdate()`function of the connect wrapper until `nestingLevel === renderedNestingLevel-1`.

Best regards

Comment: I think you should be passing down the entire `cat` object here, then when you want to remove, you call a function in the container component.

Comment: In the example of the cat that is what I would be doing. In the real world, things are more complicated unfortunately :(

Comment: I'll make an example for you, hang on.

Comment: Thank you very much but I know how to do that, its just not possible for several reasons, performance being one and that I need to rearchitect huge parts of the application. I discovered that behaviour very late unfortunately. I thought as a given that props change according to the tree, just like in plain React.

Comment: I think you'll need to share an example. As you say, redux v5 implemented a solution to this. Without seeing how you've managed to reproduce this problem it's difficult to help.

Comment: Hello Rajit, I'm trying to reproduce the issue now. What I found out is that if I cloneDeep() my state everything works fine. This hints at state corruption on my side and the problem not having anything to-do with connect().

Comment: @Mythli I'm having a similar issue. Where did you do a `cloneDeep()`? Just so I can see if that's my issue too.

Comment: I did it everywhere and it only worked on the basic level which absolutely made no sense. I'm sorry for not having answered earlier. I was in holiday the last weeks. The issue was just worked around so far though. Would be happe to pair debug or anything if you are interested. tobias at web-bee.org or skype Mythli93. Best regards. I can also share my workaround with you if you want.